# useSelector hook for functions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I can't use the actions and state elements, as my component has its own props.
So i am using useSelector (react hook) and would like to do the same for actions, but can't figure out how to do it... Any idea?

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  item: Item;
  theFunctionIWouldLikeToUse: Function;
}

const MyComponent= ({
  item, theFunctionIWouldLikeToUse
}: MyComponentProps ) => {

  const myStateItem: any= useSelector(
    (state: State) => state.myStateItem,
  ) ; //I would like to do the same for the function
};
```

Can I use useSelector  or useDispatch to get my function, which is currently in connect?

```
export default connect(() => ({}), {
  theFunctionIWouldLikeToUse,
})(withTranslation('admin')(MyComponent));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want dispatch actions, you can use `useDispatch`

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

...
dispatch(theFunctionIWouldLikeToUse());
// or dispatch({type: "action_name"});
...
```